# MySQL Won't update

Tags: upgrade, updates, mysql

I'm updating my server after a year of being off, and running all the update commands to secure everything.

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
MySQL stop/waiting
(infinite loading)
```

It is stuck, I can turn off the system and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to skip the update; but the problem still remains. I'm not sure what is causing this, any fix?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved, but it took multiple times to fix. The first command after login must be

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and it doesn't due the stop/waiting during setup of the update. It must of been an issue with the previous version of `mysql` but here's the answer for anyone else experiencing this problem.